# How to fix leap second sleep issue without reboot

Tags: linux, leapsecond

I found that after the latest leap second insertion (2016-12-31 23:59:60), our CentOS7 application that has worker threads sleeping for 1 second between jobs, started to wake the sleeping threads immediately instead of in a second.
In general, all sleeps are awake 1 second ahead of expected wake time.

The simplest and working solution is to reboot the box. But that is not desirable in our case.
Is there a way to fix this without rebooting?

PS. For reference, here's a simple program in C++ that reproduces the issue.

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


// this has to be run in a thread to be able to detect the issue
void check_thread()
{
    size_t expected_delay = 1000;
    cout << "Expected delay: " << expected_delay << " ms" << endl;
    boost::posix_time::ptime t1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    boost::posix_time::ptime t2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
    size_t actual_delay = (t2 - t1).total_milliseconds();
    cout << "Actual delay: " << actual_delay << " ms" << endl;
    if (abs(expected_delay - actual_delay) > 900) {
        cout << "Too big delay difference: " << (expected_delay - actual_delay) << endl;
        cout << "Possible leap second issue" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "No issues found" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group g;
    g.create_thread(check_thread);
    g.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Building:

```
g++ sleep_test.cpp -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -Wl,-Bdynamic -rdynamic -pthread
```

Comment: You'll have to restart the application. In future, apply updates in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Troy said, on RHEL7 systems that had not updated tzdata by the moment the leap second is applied, and not running ntpd, an extra step is required - manually set time 1 second forward, then revert it:

```
date -s "+1 sec"
date -s "-1 sec"
```

Answer (score 6):

Is your system time synched with `ntpd` or `ptp`? If not, update your `tzdata` package.

> For systems not synchronized by ntpd or ptp an updated tzdata package
>   that contains the December 31st leap second is required. The updated
>   tzdata package was released as part of RHEA-2016-1982, and any systems
>   using RHEL 7 that are not synchronized by ntpd or ptp should update to
>   tzdata-2016g-2.el7, or a later version, to receive this fix.

[Resolve Leap Second Issues in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/15145)

Comment: Installing a more recent tzdata-2016j-1.el7 does not fix the issue.
Probably, it should be installed prior the leap second is inserted to help.

Any other solutions?

Comment: I've found another solution: set time 1 second forward, then revert it.

Comment: @AnatolyMoskovsky If that was your solution, you can create an answer and mark it.